All elements are highlighted in antd sidebar menu - React+Vite
I'm having a problem that when I produce a sidebar menu that links to 4 pages, when I click one element in the menu, all the elements are highlighted, my expectation is to only highlight the element that I clicked and open the page corresponding to that element.
App.jsx
import { useState } from 'react'
import Menulist from './Components/Menulist'
import { Button, Layout, theme  } from 'antd'
import {MenuUnfoldOutlined, MenuFoldOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons'
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

import ToggleThemeButton from './Components/ToggleThemeButton'

import Files from './Pages/Files'
import Images from './Pages/Images'
import Statistics from './Pages/Statistics'
import About from './Pages/About'


const { Header, Sider } = Layout
function App() {
  const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true)  
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false)

  const toggleTheme = () =>{
    setDarkTheme(!darkTheme)
  }
  const {
    token: {colorBgContainer}
  } = theme.useToken()
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
          <Sider collapsed={collapsed}
          collapsible 
          theme={darkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light'}
          trigger = {null}> 
            <Menulist darkTheme = {darkTheme}/>  
            <ToggleThemeButton darkTheme={darkTheme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme}/>
            </Sider>
            <Layout>
              <Header style={{padding: 0, background: colorBgContainer}}>
              <Button type='text' 
              className="toggle"
              onClick={() => setCollapsed(!collapsed)}
              icon={collapsed ? <MenuUnfoldOutlined/> : <MenuFoldOutlined/>}/>  
              </Header> 
            </Layout>
        </Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/files" element={<Files/>} />
          <Route path="/images" element={<Images/>} />
          <Route path="/statistics" element={<Statistics/>} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </>
  )
}

export default App;

Menulist.jsx (Sidebar menu)
import React from "react";
import {Menu } from 'antd'
import { InfoCircleOutlined, FileOutlined, FileImageOutlined, BarChartOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons' 
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Menulist = ({ darkTheme }) =>{
    return(
        <Menu theme={darkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light'} mode='inline' className="menu-bar">
            <Link to ="/files">
                <Menu.Item key="files" icon={<FileOutlined/>}> Files</Menu.Item>
            </Link>

            <Link to ="/images">
                <Menu.Item key="images" icon={<FileImageOutlined/>}> Images </Menu.Item>    
            </Link>

            <Link to ="/statistics">
                <Menu.Item key="statistics" icon={<BarChartOutlined/>}> Statistics </Menu.Item>
            </Link>

            <Link to ="/about">
                <Menu.Item key="about" icon={<InfoCircleOutlined/>}> About  </Menu.Item>
            </Link>
            
        </Menu>
    )
}

export default Menulist;

all 4 pages are following by File.jsx, Images.jsx, Statistics.jsx, About.jsx and all of them are only contains paragraph for testing purposes.
I haven't tried anything since I was stuck and lack of understanding the Ant-design.

the problem is occur when I set the links and routes to pages and App.jsx, the frontend before then worked fine with all features i set before
